# Knp_paginator template issue

Tags: symfony4

I have a small issue on symfony 4.12  with knp_paginator bundle I want to apply a template for it I create a knp_paginator.yaml  in config/packages/test because it didn't generate it

knp_paginator:
  page_range: 5
    page_name: page
    sort_field_name: sort
    sort_direction_name: direction
    distinct: true
    filter_field_name: filterField 
    filter_value_name: filterValue
  template:
    pagination: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/twitter_bootstrap_v3_pagination.html.twig'
    sortable: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/twitter_bootstrap_v3_sortable_link.html.twig'

and in my repository

```
 $query=$query->getQuery();
    return $this->paginator->paginate(
        $query,
        1,
        2
    );
```

I tried all things but the only result I obtain is the simple paginator :  <<<12>>>

Comment: Have you imported bootstrap in your css ?

Comment: I use the CDN links in the main page which I extended in the other pages.

Comment: I'm not sure but try to change the placement of file from config/packages/test to config/packages

Comment: Think you very much it's working !!!! I spent nearly 3 days looking for the answer I've never thought about that

Comment: but I've just noticed that it doesn't work I clic on the next button to show the other results but it stays on the first results ,but I checked the link it has been changed to the write number

Comment: I traite the pagination in the controller instead of the repository and it's working !think you again for your help